Map(yaml file) in rviz2 is not shown correctly in navigation2
I am implementing a robot in simulation using ros2. I generated a map using slam_toolbox package, the generated map was good as you see here. When i execute the navigation launch file, the map is not rendering okayish, it's like grey in color like this
.
and when the robot localize the environment, the local_costmap and global_costmap is not receiving the map,

I really don't know what causes this. Can someone help me on what did i do wrong?
This is my repo for your reference to see the implementation. This is the launch file log shows in the terminal output.

What do your logs say?

updated the question with the launch log file location in the repo.

Changing the use_sim_time as False instead of True in the yaml file makes the global_costmap and local_costmap recieves map. Now the simulation works as expected.
